# Kohana 3: How can I pass full control to another action within my controller?

Tags: kohana-3

In my controller, I have a before() function that calls `parent::before()` and then does some additional processing once the parent returns. based on a specific condition, I want to "save" the original request and pass execution to a specific action. Here is my before() function.

```
public function before() {
        parent::before();
        $this->uri = Request::Instance()->uri;
        $match = ORM::factory('survey_tester')
                    ->where('eid','=',$this->template->user->samaccountname)
                    ->find();
        if (!$match->loaded()) {
            self::action_tester("add",$this->template->user);
        }
    }
```

And the action that is being called..

```
public function action_tester($op=null,$user=null) {
        $testers                            = ORM::factory('survey_tester')->find_all();
        $tester                         = array();
        $this->template->title              = 'Some new title';
        $this->template->styles         = array('assets/css/survey/survey.css' => 'screen');
        $this->template->scripts            = array('assets/js/survey/tester.js');

        $tester['title']                        = $this->template->title;
        $tester['user']                     = $this->template->user;

        switch ($op) {
            case "add":
                $tester = ORM::factory('survey_tester');
                $tester->name = $user->displayname;
                $tester->email = $user->mail;
                $tester->division = $user->division;
                $tester->eid = $user->samaccountname;
                if ($tester->save()) {
                    $this->template->content = new View('pages/survey/tester_add', $admin);
                } else {
                    $this->template->content = new View('pages/survey/tester_error', $admin);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

This all seems to work fine. This is designed to prompt the user for a specific piece of information that is not provided by $user (populated by LDAP) if this is the first time they are hitting the controller for any reason.

The problem is the views are not rendering. Instead control passes back to whatever action was originally requested. This controller is called survey. If i browse to http://my.site.com/survey and login with new user info, the record gets written and i get the action_index views instead of my action_tester views.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**: I managed to get this working (sort-of) by using `$this->request->action = 'tester';` but I'm not sure how to add/set new params for the request yet.

Comment: Why `self::action_tester()` and not `$this->action_tester()`?

Comment: It's just the way the person I had started learning from was doing it. It doesn't matter though, `$this->action_tester()` does the same thing. I still have the same issue.

Comment: About partial solution. You can store additional params in session, Controller properties, or view object ($this->template->set(...)). This data will be available in the executing action

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are calling your method (action_tester), but then Kohana is still going to call the original action after the before method is called, which is going to change the response content overwriting the changed made in action_tester().

You can change the action being called (after before is called) inside your before() method:

```
$this->request->action('action_tester');
```

After the before method is called, it should then call the new Action (action_tester) rather than the old one, but then you need to do something about the way you are passing your parameters then.

Or you could just redirect the request upon some condition:

```
if($something) {
    $this->request->redirect('controller/tester');
}
```

This doesn't seem like a nice way to do it anyway.